Understanding the factorization of conditional independence from Kevin Murphy book 2
I am reading Kevin Murphy's new book 2 (advanced topics), and I want to clarify a simple derivation. On pages 156-157, a probabilistic graphical model is factorized. The pgm is shown as follows

In the probabilistic model shown below:
$$
p(\theta, D) = p(\theta_x)p(\theta_y) \prod_{n=1}^{N} p(y_n \mid \theta_y)p(x_n \mid y_n, \theta_x) \tag{4.38}
$$
It follows that:
$$
p(\theta, D) = \left[ p(\theta_y) \prod_{n=1}^{N} p(y_n \mid \theta_y) \right] \left[ p(\theta_x) \prod_{n=1}^{N} p(x_n \mid y_n, \theta_x) \right] \tag{4.39}
$$
The next step is written as:
$$
p(\theta, D) = \left[ p(\theta_y) p(D_y \mid \theta_y) \right] \left[ p(\theta_x) p(D_x \mid \theta_x) \right] \tag{4.40}
$$
where:
$$
D_y = \{y_n\}_{n=1}^{N} \quad \text{and} \quad D_x = \{x_n, y_n\}_{n=1}^{N}.
$$
My question is: can equation $(4.40)$ follow from $(4.39)$? Specifically, equation $(4.40)$ suggests a joint probability term $p(x_n, y_n \mid \theta_x)$ instead of the conditional term $p(x_n \mid y_n, \theta_x)$ in $(4.39)$.
I understand that the following is true:
$$
p(x_n \mid y_n, \theta_x) = \frac{p(x_n, y_n \mid \theta_x)}{p(y_n \mid \theta_x)}.
$$
But, how can equation $(4.40)$ follow unless we assume $y_n$ and $\theta_x$ are independent? Observing $x_n$ makes $y_n$ and $\theta_x$ dependent according to d-separation rule. Can someone explain the validity of the transition from $(4.39)$ to $(4.40)$?
PS: I already asked this question in math.stackoverflow but did not get any answer.

If you look at the graph, you see that $p(y_n \mid \theta_x) = p(y_n)$. ($\theta_x$ doesn't tell you anything about $y_n$.) My knee-jerk guess without looking into the book would be that the equality sign should be a $\propto$ instead? You should open an issue.

Thanks for commenting. But according to d-separation rule, this is a case of common effect and the middle node ($X$). So $y_n \not \perp \theta_x | x_n$. Am I getting something wrong? Or, alternatively can we prove $p(y_n|\theta_x) = p(y_n)$?

If $x_n$ were not given then I totally get your point. But, do let me know if I am missing something.

You're right that $y_n \not \perp \theta_x \mid x_n$ but we still have $p(y_n \mid \theta_x) = p(y_n)$ simply since $\theta_x$ is not a parent of $y_n$ (and we're not conditioning on the collider $x_n$). That implies that $p(x_n \mid y_n, \theta_x) = p(x_n, y_n \mid \theta_x) / p(y_n \mid \theta_x) = p(x_n, y_n \mid \theta_x) / p(y_n) \propto p(x_n, y_n \mid \theta_x)$.

I get your point $p(y_n,\theta_x) = p(y_n)p(\theta_x)$

(Edit: that should have been "... since $\theta_x$ is neither a parent nor a child of $y_n$ ...")
